# Не применяются стили css

Tags: html, css

Не применяются стили css к классу video_text(h4), что делать?

```css
.video {
  background-image: url('img/bg photo.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.video_description {
  text-align: center;
}

.video_image {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.video_image:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}


}
.video_title {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 337px;
  height: 22px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.video_text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 551px;
  height: 43px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.75;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.video_time {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 36px;
  height: 10px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.71;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #c7b299;
}
```

```html
<section class="video">
  <div class="video_description">
    <img src="img/icon-play.png" class="video_image">
    <h4 class="video_title">Waxom Video Presentation</h4>
    <p class="video_text">Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium.</p>
    <p class="video_time">03:26</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас перед .video_title лишняя закрывающая скобка. Уберите ее и все заработает.

Answer (score 4):

У вас ведь `h4 class="video_title` стоит выше (отдельно) от `div` с классом `video_text` . Что бы применить стили к вашему `h4` нужно в `ccs` прописать так:

```
.video_description h4{
}
```

или

```
h4.video_title{
}
```